# Junit 3: How to run only one testcase from a test class

Tags: junit, automated-tests, junit3

I am using JUnit 3 and I have a test class which had 4 test methods.
CLass A:
test1()
test2()
test3()
test4()

Now I have written another test class B, which has the following methods:
test10()
test11()
test12()

Now, test10() requires test1() (of class A) as a pre requisite. 
SO I would like to run only test1() from Class A, when inside test10() of class B.

Could someone please hep me with this?

Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Comment: I would suggest you to remove this link between the tests. Unit tests should always run independently.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like code that should be extracted to a helper class.  But if you must do this, it is just regular Java code.

In test B:

```
public void test100() {
  ClassA helper = new ClassA("");
  helper.setUp();
  helper.test1();
  // your actual logic for test100
}
```

Also, consider better names if your tests are really named test100(), test101(), etc.